# Change year label position of moderntimeline

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

When I use the package `moderntimeline` for creating a timeline in my CV (with stile `moderncv`), like:

`\tlcventry{2010}{2012}...`

I find the position of year lable is not quite correct. In the picture below, 2010 is after 2012, but 2005 is before 2009.
How can i move the 2010 forward?

[image: timeline]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is an answer to your question, so please give feedback about it

Answer (score 1):

It is right. With your command `tlcventry`, you ask to draw a bar which starts with 2010 (at left) and ends with 2012 (at right).

A solution is the command `tllabelcventry` like this one:

```
\tllabelcventry[blu]{2010}{2012}{2010--2012}{...}
  {...}{...}{}
  {...}
```

That puts all the data over the bar, and in order.

Comment: Ah i see, that means it depends the width of the bar. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. This is a solution. Another is redefine the command, but is more complex.